# Calling javascript function within Chrome.tabs.Query

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

i am getting the following error while calling the given javascript code

```
"Error in response to tabs.query: ReferenceError: printTabs is not defined"
```

Could some one help me out of this.

```
var tabinator = {
  fillBody: function() {
    chrome.tabs.query(
      {}, 
      function(tabs) { 
        for(var i=0; i<tabs.length; i++) { 
         printTabs(tabs[i].title,tabs[i].id);
        }
      }
    );
  },

printTabs:function(x,y,z){
console.log(x+y+z);
}
};

// --- Execution starts here ---
document.addEventListener(
  'DOMContentLoaded', 
  function () {
    tabinator.fillBody();
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `printTabs` is function defined in `tabinator` object. You have to call it giving reference to `tabinator`object using `this`. You also have to make sure that you pass this reference to the callback function of `chrome.tabs.query` using variable `that`.

Try this,

```
var tabinator = {
  fillBody: function() {
    var that = this;
    chrome.tabs.query(
      {}, 
      function(tabs) { 
        for(var i=0; i<tabs.length; i++) { 
         that.printTabs(tabs[i].title,tabs[i].id);
        }
      }
    );
  },

printTabs:function(x,y,z){
    console.log(x+y+z);
}
};

// --- Execution starts here ---
document.addEventListener(
  'DOMContentLoaded', 
  function () {
    tabinator.fillBody();
  }
);
```

Comment: thanks @kelsadita why cant i directly give this in place of that.

Comment: @iHappyk callback function of `chrome.tabs.query` gets the context of that function but you need to get the context of `tabinator` in order to refer `printTabs` defined in it.

Comment: i want to create a shortcut icon on chrome browser something to similiar to default scroll bar of chrome. is it possible.? if yes how..??

Comment: i have variable defined in the Tabinator, how to access it.